# Ruby calculate How many different squares are there in a grid of NxN squares?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I worked on ruby exercice to create a method for calculate the square in a grid NxN

like If n = 1, there is one 1-by-1 square = 1.

```
 If n = 3, there is one 3-by-3 square, four 2-by-2 squares and nine 1-by-1 squares = 14.
```

If we continued the above sequence for an arbitrary n, then we would have one n-by-n square, four (n - 1)-by-(n - 1) squares, nine (n - 2)-by-(n - 2) squares, ... , and n2 1-by-1 squares.

i would like to know how can i do to get this in ruby

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". We'd like to see evidence of your effort towards solving the problem. SO isn't code or tutorial writing service. We expect you to do the research and try, try more, then try again, then ask.

Answer (score 2):

Generally for an **n x n** square grid, the total number of squares is defined by

**n² + (n-1)² + (n-2)² + ... + 1.**

In Ruby you could do something like this:

```
class Number

  def squares_counter(n)
    (1..n).map {|e| e*e }.inject(:+)
  end

end
```

`map` creates an array of *square numbers* from `1` to `n` then `inject` sums them up. Using this we can calculate the number of squares on a chessboard:

```
num = Number.new
puts num.squares_counter(8) #=> 204
```

Comment: You can also calculate the [sum of the first n squares](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjq89bc3frMAhVk54MKHc8fAysQFghVMAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fproofwiki.org%2Fwiki%2FSum_of_Sequence_of_Squares&usg=AFQjCNHx53sN43EA66kkI0JuS_p5yK0-iQ&bvm=bv.122676328,d.amc) in O(1) time. 
(n(n+1)(2n+1))/6

Comment: Good one, sagar. Readers: if it's unclear why this works, think of counting the number of `m`x`m` squares in a `n`x`n` square, `m <= n`. The top-left corner of each `m`x`m` square must be in the first `n-(m-1)` rows and `n-(m-1)` columns, which contains `(n-(m-1))**2` `1`x`1` squares. So the total number of squares of all sizes equals `(n-(m-1))**2` summed over `m = 1,..,n`, which equals the answer given.

Comment: @DaunteMack excellent point; your approach would of course be much better.